# Why gcc on Ubuntu doesn't warn for -Wnon-literal-null-conversion but on macOS?

Tags: c, macos, ubuntu, gcc, compilation

I came across this *issue* and I don't know how to evaluate it since I just started learning C and gcc.
I created a function to return an array of `null` terminated strings. Strings are terminated with `'\0'` but the array also terminated with `'\0'`. And this was working *fine* since it didn't warn me on Ubuntu with flags `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` but when I tried it with macOS it fails to compile (`expression which evaluates to zero treated as a null pointer constant of type 'char *' [-Werror,-Wnon-literal-null-conversion]`).

So, I read about the difference between `'\0'` and `0` (`NULL`) and why I should terminate array with `NULL`.
My question is how can I catch it on Ubuntu as well? What default settings make this difference between them?

`gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0`

`Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)`

Comment: @9769953 yes you're right, I just noticed that. And yes it clang on Ubuntu warns about it too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @9769953 It's a simple function that takes a string and  splits it to words and return as an array of strings.

Comment: And I ask this because it was on the exam which I couldn't go further because of this issue (I have to pass questions one by one). We work on Ubuntu and evaluator program should be running on the same environment as I'm told. I got to see the error log after the exam:

$> cc -Wextra -Wall -Werror main.c ft_split.c -o user_exe
ft_split.c:53:14: error: expression which evaluates to zero treated as a null pointer constant of type 'char *' [-Werror,-Wnon-literal-null-conversion]

So, it was compiled with gcc, not clang.

Answer (score 1):

The default **gcc** on macOS behaves differently from **gcc** on linus because it is a totally different compiler: as evidenced with the `--version` output, **gcc** on macOS is by default an alias for **clang**.

**clang** is installed as a part of X-Code and supports most of the warnings of **gcc**, and many more. The default settings are somewhat different so you may get a warning on the mac that you would not get on linux with **gcc**.

It is a good idea to enable more warnings with **gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror** in your Makefile to catch many subtle and not so subtle problems at compile time.  **clang** also supports **-Weverything** but some of this extra level of analysis might be a bit obnoxious.  **clang -Wall -Wextra** enables some warnings that **gcc** lacks.

In your case, the warning tells you that you use a character constant `'\0'`, which has type `int` and a value of `0` as a null terminator for an array of `char *`.  While `'\0'` will be treated as a null pointer like `0` would, it is confusing to use a character constant in place of a more explicit null pointer constant such as `(char *)0` or `NULL` (or `nullptr` as of c23).

The warning (enabled by default) is supported by both **clang** and **gcc** to help identify potential programmer mistakes. Yet **clang**'s implementation is more complete:  **clang** detects the incorrect use of `'\0'` for assignment expressions, not just for comparison as **gcc** does.  It is likely the exam system uses **clang**, not **gcc** (it also seems to run on windows, but both compilers are available for this target). See [this godbolt session](https://godbolt.org/z/ErKGb1Yzo) for a comparison of compiler versions.

Note for example that it would be incorrect to write:

```
    execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "Hello world!\n", '\0');
```

or even

```
    execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "Hello world!\n", 0);
```

because these null `int` values would not be passed as `char *` values which `execl` expects. Furthermore `char` pointers and `int` have a different representation on most 64-bit architectures.

You must write:

```
    execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "Hello world!\n", NULL);
```

or

```
    execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "Hello world!\n", (char *)0);
```

Comment: Hello,
I use the same flags (-Wextra -Wall -Werror) on both OS. I figured out what was wrong with my code but what I didn't get it is why it didn't catch.

This is log I got after the exam:
$> cc -Wextra -Wall -Werror main.c ft_split.c -o user_exe
ft_split.c:53:14: error: expression which evaluates to zero treated as a null pointer constant of type 'char *' [-Werror,-Wnon-literal-null-conversion]
        result[j] = '\0';
                    ^~~~
1 error generated.
Could not compile 'user_exe'

So, they used cc with the flags I used but mine didn't catch it during the exam.

Comment: @ServetTonga: the warning is supported by both **clang** and **gcc**, but **clang**'s implementation is more complete.  **clang** detects the incorrect use of `'\0'` for assignment, not just for comparison as **gcc** does.  It is likely the exam system runs on windows and uses **clang**, not **gcc**. See [this godbolt session](https://godbolt.org/z/ErKGb1Yzo) for a comparison of compiler versions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and sharing this great tool. It definitely helps to understand the difference.